# Isotope filtering with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am working on using the isotope plugin with bootstrap and have run into some trouble. I need the `col-md-4` div around the isotope element `gallery-image-a`, so the `.grid` is not a direct parent of the isotope element. Once I get rid of the `col-md-4` div that I need, the plugin works.

Was wondering if anyone knows of a way to keep the existing markup while maintaining the functionality of the [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) plugin?

HTML Snippet 1

```
  <span class="menu-button" id="food-button">Food</span>
  <span class="menu-button" id="staff-button">Staff</span>
  <span class="menu-button" id="all-button">All</span>
```

HTML Snippet 2

```
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row grid">
           <div class="col-md-4">
               <a class="gallery-image-a food"></a>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
               <a class="gallery-image-a staff"></a>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
               <a class="gallery-image-a food"></a>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
               <a class="gallery-image-a staff"></a>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
               <a class="gallery-image-a food"></a>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
               <a class="gallery-image-a staff"></a>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.gallery-image-a {
    display:block;
    height:360px;
    background-position:center center;
    transition: ease all 950ms;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:10px solid #fff;
    background-size:cover;
    background-image: url('http://animalpetdoctor.homestead.com/acat1.jpg');
}
```

JavaScript

```
$grid = $('.grid');
$grid.isotope();

$('#food-button,#staff-button, #all-button').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var className = id.replace("-button", "");

    if (className == 'all') {
        $grid.isotope({ filter: '*' });
        return false;
    }
    $grid.isotope({ filter: '.' + className });
});
```

Comment: @dandavis can you elaborate on what you mean by 'wont validate'? The bootstrap is perfectly valid as it came from the official docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 problems. First, the filter works on children so change HTML to this

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row grid">
           <div class="col-md-4 food">
               <a class="gallery-image-a"></a>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4 staff">
               <a class="gallery-image-a"></a>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4 food">
               <a class="gallery-image-a"></a>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4 staff">
               <a class="gallery-image-a"></a>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4 food">
               <a class="gallery-image-a"></a>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4 staff">
               <a class="gallery-image-a"></a>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

second, even if it does work, you won't see it. add min-width to class

```
min-width: 100px;
```

here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shirandror/rvnrk2kc/

Comment: Worked great. Toda Raba ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining the itemSelector option to .col-md-4 or better declaring a designated class for that like "grid-item"?

```
$('.grid').isotope({
   itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});
```

EDIT:

I put up a working example on codepen:
http://codepen.io/iCymiCy/pen/grwpXp?editors=1111

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your codepen code does not demonstrate any functionality. I appreciate your feedback however.